# Android: how to pass webview in intent.putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I'm new to Android and am trying to make a simple app.

I want to create an activity which displays a webview loaded with an html. For the user experience to be good, I want to preload the html into the webview and pass that to the activity that displays it. I'm not able to find any examples online which show how to pass webviews into the putExtra method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare is right; you'll want to manage a hidden WebView on your page, load it, and then show it when the user wants to see it. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529815/preloading-a-webview-and-then-switching-to-its-activity) has some code that seems pretty close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

> I have 2 activites: the first one preloads a url into a webview; the second one adds the webview to a layout and sets the content view with the layout.

That is not going to work. Just have one activity.

> I want to pass the empty webview through intent.putExtra into the first activity.

That is not possible. Just have one activity.

> I want to pass it into the second activity for adding it to the layout and setting the content view

One activity cannot show another activity's views. Just have one activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have one activity, I want to preload my webview, and then display it at a later point of time. If I call my preload() method in the onCreate() method of the activity, how can I call the display() method at some later point in time? I looked for a way to call methods on an activity, but it seems like the only thing the caller can do is start the activity.

Comment: Just to clarify: I do the preloading stuff when the activity starts (onCreate), but want to display it (add to layout, set content view) at a later point in time. How do I do that?

Comment: @tldr: Have the `WebView` set to `android:visibility="gone"` at the outset, then make it visible when you want to show it.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to call methods on the activity other than onCreate.